How to Collect Data Across Iframes on a Shared Domain Without Interacting With the Main Page?
I am working on an implementation involving hosted fields for securely handling credit card information. My setup includes the following:

An HTML page containing 4 iframes:

3 iframes for credit card details (card number, validity, and CVV).
1 admin iframe for managing and collecting the data from the credit card iframes.


All iframes are hosted on the same shared domain, ensuring the same-origin policy is not violated.


I want the admin iframe to directly collect data from the 3 credit card iframes without involving the main page. The main page should remain unaware of the data exchange between the admin iframe and the credit card iframes.
I am unable to implement this direct communication between the admin iframe and the credit card iframes without going through the main page.

The main page must remain entirely decoupled from the data flow between the admin iframe and the credit card iframes.
All iframes are on the same shared domain.

How can I implement direct communication between the admin iframe and the credit card iframes under these constraints? Are there any techniques or best practices for iframe-to-iframe communication that do not rely on the main page?
This is part of a hosted fields implementation for payment processing, so security is a top priority. The admin iframe acts as a controller to collect and manage sensitive information securely.
Any guidance, sample code, or recommended patterns would be greatly appreciated.
Let me know if you'd like any adjustments or additional details added!
I have tried the following approaches:

Using the window.parent and window.frames APIs, but this requires communication through the main page, which I want to avoid.
Exploring postMessage for iframe communication, but I can't seem to bypass the main page effectively.


https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API is almost certainly what you are looking for.

If I were you, then I would embed the 3 other frames in the admin one. You could also use localStorage if you were desperate to stop communication and wanting to keep your structure. Set some item on localStorage for each part of the card, then use setInterval in the admin iframe to receive that information.
<!-- Example #1 -->
<iframe src="admin">
   #document
      <iframe src="card-1"></iframe>
      <iframe src="card-2"></iframe>
      <iframe src="card-3"></iframe>
</iframe>
<!-- Example #2 -->
<iframe src="card-1">
   #document
      <input placeholder="card number"/>
      <script>
         document.querySelector("input").onkeyup = function () { 
            localStorage.setItem("card-number", this.value)
         }
      </script>
</iframe>
<iframe src="card-2">...</iframe>
<iframe src="card-3">...</iframe>
<iframe src="admin">
   #document
      <script>
         let card = "", cvv = ""
         let intv = setInterval(() => {
            card = localStorage.getItem("card-number")
            cvv = localStorage.getItem("cvv")
            if (card && CVV) clearInterval(intv) // have all information now
         }, 1000)
      </script>
</iframe>

No matter what though, you won't be able to stop the main page from accessing the iframe elements... Why can't you just combine all of the iframes into one? There is no security disadvantage in doing so.

I don’t want to combine everything into one iframe. I’m trying to implement hosted fields. Thank you very much for the answer, but this solution doesn’t help me. I need each field to be in a separate iframe, and for the main iframe to communicate with them without referring directly to the main page.
